# Why am i not getting depth of field in my picture

Tags: camera, depth-of-field

I cannot figure out why I am not getting a blurry background. I have the f stops all the way down. I have the distance set on my object. If I set the focus object to my object, Everything goes blurry with no focus. I have tried to scale up my whole scene as much as I could and still no blurry background. Does anyone know something else i could try.

[video](https://imgur.com/gallery/GVMIlnT)

Answer (score 0):

Depth of Field is a camera effect.  When you turn your view in this video you're no longer looking through the camera, so it won't be present.

F-stop is the value that mainly controls the strength of the effect, but it's also dependent on things like focal length and distance to the object, and this can make overall scene scale important.

Model to real life scale and use realistic values in your camera and you should get a plausible result.  Figure out what size of a print that picture should be.  Your camera in that situation would be a literal camera with a sensor size and a lens with an actual focal length and an f value somewhere between 1.4 and let's say 16.

Recommend first that you start a new scene and play around with the camera and a couple of cubes to gain a better understanding before making drastic changes to this scene you've worked hard on.

Comment: im talking about no depth of field in the camera. I knew that there is no depth of field in the viewer. I was just moving around to show you guys the distance between the objects.

Comment: why is there no depth of field in the camera?

Comment: The back picture looks blurry in the first second of the video, but not as blurry as it should given these settings.  It should be practically a smear of fleshtone.  I'm not sure, that's why I recommend trying to recreate the scenario in a new file just as a sanity check.

Comment: @RickyBascom - Does this answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

@AllenSimpson is correct ... here just an example ...

[image]

Note: I used **Cycles** engine ...

[image]

For **Eevee** just switch to Eevee is blurred all, so some adjustment is needed...

[image]

I had to set bigger distance between objects to get effect ... so probably some limits to keep it real time ... and mainly enable under *Scene Properties > Depth of Field* enable **Jitter Camera**

[image]